# Get YouTube Search List from YouTube API

Tags: api, search, youtube

I'm trying to get a search list for a specific keyword from the YouTube API.

I've tried: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&q=elanco&key={MY API KEY}

And it only gives me the first 50 Results. So I changed "maxResults" to equal 2000.

But then this error occurs:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid value '2000'. Values must be within the range: [0, 50]",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "maxResults"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value '2000'. Values must be within the range: [0, 50]"
 }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get more than 50 results? My keyword generates around 1500 results, I want to be able to see all of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), maxResults param having restriction [*Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5*].

So per one request you can get the 50 records at Max, if you see in the result of your first hit , you will get nextPageToken field (starting from first , except the last page,as this is the last page ) and prevPageToken (starting from second page, as there will be no prev page for the first page) field in response to the request.

Now we can use these values (nextPageToken/prevPageToken) to fetch records for the next or prev 50 records by passing the value to the query parameter

> **pageToken** = < value of nextPageToken for the next set of records>
>   or < for prev use prevPageToken>.

In short, Add the pageToken param to the subsequent requests till the count equals pageInfo.totalResults !!!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

Use the `nextPageToken` to get the next `resultset`. There is some restrictions, the API can only return max of 50 restultet at a time. But using the `nexPageToken` element you can get the next 50 `resultset`

```
    {
     "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
     "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/FSbRmodfOD2HSQzA29X7Tn2Mupc\"",
     "

nextPageToken": "CAIQAA"


 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 199,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "items": [
```